# TypeScript source map files don't work with Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, typescript, web-essentials, source-maps

I'm trying to get TypeScript source debugging working in Chrome, but I'm running into two specific and perhaps related problems.

The first is that the comment generated by the TypeScript/WebEssentials compiler that's supposed to identify the location of the source map file looks like this:

`//sourceMappingUrl=MySourceFile.js.map`

But Chrome won't read that file. It seems expect that the comment will look like this:

`//@ sourceMappingUrl=MySourceFile.js.map`

If I manually change the comment to that, and refresh my page, then magically the references to all the .ts files show up as sources in the Chrome Developer Tools.

However, that leads to my second problem, as the files don't actually get loaded. The .ts source file that Chrome *should* be trying to download is `http://localhost/MySourceFile.ts`, but the one that it's *actually* trying to download is `http://localhost/C:/source/web/MySourceFile.ts`. That sort of makes sense, as the opening attributes of MySourceFile.js.map look like this:

`{"version":3,"file":"tmp1523.tmp","sources":["C:/source/web/MySourceFile.ts"`

But that obviously doesn't work with Chrome, as it interprets the source-map location to be entirely relative, and IIS (quite correctly) won't serve up any URL looking like `http://localhost/C:/source/web/MySourceFile.ts`.

So, with respect to these two problems, is it Chrome or the TypeScript source-map feature that's doing it wrong? And what's the recommended way of doing this?

I'm using Chrome 25.0.1323.1 dev-m, with TypeScript 0.8.1 and WebEssentials 1.8.5.

Comment: This may be a Web Essentials issue. Either that or the compiler behaviour has changed. Due to some bugs WE 1.8.2 and later I'm on TS 0.8.0 / WE 1.8.1 and have source maps working correctly in Chrome. My source map begins `{"version":3,"file":"pe.plugins.js","sources":["pe.plugins.ts"] ... (etc)` and the JS annotation is `//@ sourceMappingURL=pe.plugins.js.map`. Not sure if the new source map functionality is compatible with Chrome, now they've changed it to work in VS/IE ?

Comment: See this also (the update half way down the page): http://www.johnpapa.net/debug-with-typescript08/ - `some earlier versions of Web Essentials 2012 may interfere with the TypeScript debugging ... I have had much success using Web Essentials 2012 version 1.8.8.1.`

Comment: @JcFx - That last was it. The version of WebEssentials at http://madskristensen.net/custom/webessentials2012.vsix (currently 1.8.9.66, vs. the 1.8.5 available on http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6) generates the map files correctly. Throw it into an answer and I'll give you credit :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with version 1.8.5 of [Web Essentials](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6) (the version currently available from the Visual Studio Gallery). The latest nightly build (at time of writing http://madskristensen.net/custom/webessentials2012.vsix) fixes the problem and generates the map linkage correctly.

Comment: I've tried debugging typescript in chrome enabled source maps in chrome and also  tried debugging in ie10 but the breakpoints never get hit in vs 2012

Comment: @Nikos - The sourcemap support in TypeScript doesn't seem to be working very well yet. I eventually turned it off - just too many bugs. Among other things, with VS2012, if you refresh your page in IE, none of your TS breakpoints will get hit. So I do most of my debugging in-browser rather than in VS2012.

Comment: It has always worked well for me in Chrome. I set my breakpoints using 'debugger' normally (or using the Chrome F12 tools) and when it breaks, I get the ts source (not the js) and can view the values of ts members etc. Other than a quick test when they introduced the feature, I haven't used VS2012 to debug - it seems a bit unwieldy for client-side code.

Comment: @Nikos - TS 0.8.2 may address some of your issues: "We’ve further improved the Visual Studio TypeScript debugging experience in 0.8.2.  The debugger will now honor breakpoints after F5 (refresh) during a debug session.  Combined with the addition of compile-on-save, the workflow to edit and debug a web app is as easy as saving the edited changes and refreshing the browser." http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/01/21/announcing-typescript-0-8-2.aspx

Comment: @JcFx thanks mate! great work! I advocate TS in pretty much every company I visit now.

Comment: @Nikos I don't know what you mean when you say 'it doesn't work'. Why not put what you're doing into a new question, with some screenshots and code samples, and then the community can help you figure it out?