# typescript 0.9.1 source maps not working anymore

Tags: typescript

i upgraded to version 0.9.1 of typescript... since then the source maps are no longer being downloaded and liked to by chrome... the source maps are in fact being generated but it's just that they are not being linked to... after doing a little bit of searching i ran across this link: [TypeScript source map files don't work with Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13569192/typescript-source-map-files-dont-work-with-chrome). sure enough i am experiencing a similar problem... what's happening is that the source map linking is using //# syntax instead of //@... if i manually change the js file to the latter, chrome once again picks up the source map... i also stumbled across this link: http://typescript.codeplex.com/discussions/452751. it looks like this may be a known issue but i don't see any resolution to the problem, if any... is there any sort of workaround to get source maps working again with chrome and typescript 0.9.1?????

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They changed the format of the source map reference at the bottom of your *.js file.
Change:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=[filename].js.map
```

to

```
//@ sourceMappingURL=[filename].js.map
```

See https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/1445 for more.
It looks like newer versions of Chrome will support this new format.

Comment: Here is some more information: "Previously the comment pragma was //@ but due to some issues with that and IE conditional compilation comments the decision was made to change it to //#." from http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/